# How the routers schedule multicast listeners?

Tags: udp, router, network-protocols, multicast, igmp

I want to know how router schedule Multicast listeners. For example, if 2 hosts are connected to a router, and they want to listen same multicast server, which one of the 2 gets the multicast packet first?

Comment: If your question would be closed here, I suggest to re-ask it on superuser.com .

Comment: @peterh http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ is a better fit.

Comment: @Malt I 100% agree with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will receive the packet at the same time (assuming the distance to both machines is the same).

The router doesn't send two unicast packets to two separate machines, sending one before the other. Instead, it sends a **single** multicast packets with a special [multicast MAC address](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957928.aspx) and a [multicast IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address). All machines (and routers) on the same LAN that listen to the same multicast group will receive that packet.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how router schedule Multicast listeners.

They don't.

> For example, if 2 hosts are connected to a router, and they want to listen same multicast server

There is no such thing as a 'multicast server'. There are multicast *groups,* and you can *join* those.

> which one of the 2 gets the multicast packet first?

Indeterminate. The multicast packet is sent to the internal network, and whichever host gets it first, gets it first.

You seem to think that the router sends multicasts individually to all members. It doesn't. That's a complete misunderstanding of the nature of multicasts. All the router knows is that there is at least one member of the multicast group on its 'inside' network, so it propagages the packet to that network. **Once.** It is then up to the hosts concerned to pick it up.